# Installing Elementary OS - will it automatically be added to the Grub menu?

Tags: partition, grub2, grub

I currently have Windows 7 and Linux Mint installed.

When my PC starts up, it shows me the Grub menu, it shows an entry for Mint Linux and the Windows boot menu.

I am wondering, if I was to install Elementary OS, would it be automatically added to grub or do I have to put some command in the terminal?

I also want to ask, when I boot from my Elementary OS cd, and install it, just before it finishes, it shows some kind of error saying some error about cannot install to grub or something, I've tried installing to a separate partition and alongside "Them", but had no luck.

I'm really new to Linux, and want to keep my Mint Linux and Windows 7 because I have files on them.

Comment: it will be automatically in grub menu .

Comment: Well, the first step for you is to get the install to work without errors. Worry about the grub menu entry later, which will most likely show up. Even if it doesn't show up, you can run `update-grub` from your Mint install and grub should detect elementary if it is installed correctly.